# Count(*) with a join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

This is probably very simple, but for some reason I am pulling a blank on this one..

I want to join two tables and get the total occurrences of a column in one table within another table.
    Table1

```
id | company
------------
 1 | companyA
 2 | companyB
 3 | companyC


Table2

id | company_id
------------
 1 |  2
 2 |  2
 3 |  1
 4 |  2
 5 |  3
```

The result should be:

```
company | count(*)
------------------
companyA| 1
companyB| 3
companyC| 1
```

I can't seem to get the count portion correct. I was thinking that it would be something like:

```
SELECT Table1.company, count(*)
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON
Table1.id = Table2.company_id
GROUP BY Table1.company;
```

Revised: The problem is actually that companyA and companyB come up correctly, but it's not showing companyC. I went through and double checked that there are matches in the fields for companyC which there were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `Table2.company_id` that you are joining with and **not** `Table2.id`

```
SELECT  Table1.company, count(*)
FROM    Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2 
           ON Table1.id = Table2.company_id  -- <<== here
GROUP   BY Table1.company;
```

you must define an `INDEX` (*probably UNIQUE*) on column `company` of `table` for faster performance since you are grouping it with `company`

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  Table1.company, count(Table2.company_id)
FROM    Table1 
        LEFT JOIN Table2 
           ON Table1.id = Table2.company_id  -- <<== here
GROUP   BY Table1.company;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04ef2/1)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I added more to the question to be more specific about the issue. CompanyA and companyB are showing up, but companyC is not.

Comment: oh i see, you should be using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. I'll update the answer.